# Actionlib: AttributeError: 'PoseStamped' object has no attribute 'use_start_pose'

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, actionlib, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use move base flex inside a SMACH state machine and want to call the get_path-action. The corresponding action-msg looks like this:

```
bool use_start_pose
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped start_pose
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped target_pose
float64 tolerance
string planner
uint8 concurrency_slot

---

# Predefined success codes:
uint8 SUCCESS         = 0
# 1..9 are reserved as plugin specific non-error results

# Possible error codes:
...

uint32 outcome
string message

nav_msgs/Path path

float64 cost

---
```

Since I have the target_pose stored in an array, I need to pass it to the get_path-actionServer via the goal_cb-Param of the smach_ros.SimpleActionState. Therefore, my code looks as follows:

```
sm.userdata.next_goal = [target_pose]
smach.StateMachine.add('GET_GLOBAL_PATH_IN_GOAL_CHECK_SM',
                                          smach_ros.SimpleActionState(
                                              '/move_base_flex/get_path',
                                              GetPathAction,
                                              result_cb = getPathCallback,
                                              goal_cb=set_goal_callback,
                                              input_keys=['next_goal', ...]),
                                          transitions={...})

with the goal_cb as:

def set_goal_callback(userdata, goal):
    if(userdata.next_goal[0]!=None):
        return userdata.next_goal[0]
    else:
        raise Exception("userdata.next_goal is empty.")
```

Doing so, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1602531192.400746, 0.000000]: InvalidUserCodeError: Could not execute state 'GET_GLOBAL_PATH_IN_GOAL_CHECK_SM' of type '<smach_ros.simple_action_state.SimpleActionState object at 0x7fa458342c18>': Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...Traceback...
  File "/home/faps/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages/mbf_msgs/msg/_GetPathActionGoal.py", line 165, in serialize
    buff.write(_get_struct_B3I().pack(_x.goal.use_start_pose, _x.goal.start_pose.header.seq, _x.goal.start_pose.header.stamp.secs, _x.goal.start_pose.header.stamp.nsecs))
AttributeError: 'PoseStamped' object has no attribute 'use_start_pose'
```

How do I have to modify my goal_cb to provide the Action with the required use_start_pose-bool and the start_pose-Pose? And furthermore, when I want to get the global path from my current position to the specified goal, do I even need to set the start_pose or does the get_path automatically plan from my current position when use_start_pose is false?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363274/actionlib:-attributeerror:-%27posestamped%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27use_start_pose%27/) by [Zimba96](https://answers.ros.org/users/34594/zimba96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2020-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are 3 ways to get a goal into a SimpleActionClient:

1. goal: Directly pass a goal
2. goal_key: Pass a goal from a user_data key
3. goal_cb: Execute a callback which builds the goal

I think in your case, method 1 would be the easiest. You could try something like this:

```
smach_ros.SimpleActionState(
      '/move_base_flex/get_path',
      GetPathAction,
      goal=GetPathGoal(...)
```

**Edit**: Your mistake is probably that you give a PoseStamped to the action, instead of a GetPathGoal.

---

Originally posted by [Rayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/46652/rayman/) with karma: 128 on 2020-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zimba96](https://answers.ros.org/users/34594/zimba96/) on 2020-10-13**:
Thanks for your Answer, I'll try that! For the correct understanding: the start-pose or use-start-pose-option is only relevant when you don't want to plan from your current position and therefore need to specify a start-pose, right?

**Comment by [Rayman](https://answers.ros.org/users/46652/rayman/) on 2020-10-13**:
Yes, correct!